# Why d v-select selection dropdowns inputs are empty?

Tags: vuejs2, v-select

I added v-select in Laravel 8 /vuejs 2/ bootstrap 4, but selection dropdowns inputs are empty.
I define 2 v-select elements

```
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label>Select category</label>

              <div class="select-container">
                <v-select
                  v-model="selection_category_id"
                  code="code"
                  label="label"
                  :options="categorySelectionItems"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Select option"
                ></v-select>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Platform</label>
            <div class="select-container">
              <div class="select-container">
                <v-select
                  v-model="selection_platform_id"
                  label="label"
                  code="code"
                  :options="platforms"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Select option"
                ></v-select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

add v-select to the page :

```
        import Vue from 'vue'
        import vSelect from 'vue-select'

        Vue.component('v-select', vSelect)
        import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';



  data() {
    return {
      categorySelectionItems: [], // these data are read from db
      selection_category_id: null,

      platforms: [{label: 'Canada', code: 'ca'}], // define constant array for example
      selection_platform_id: null,




    async loadCategoriesList() {
      const result = await this.callApi(
        'post',
        window.api_path + 'getCategoriesList', // READ data from db by request
        {mode: 'selection'}
      );
      if (result.status != 200) {
        this.$toaster.error(result.data.message);
        this.categories = [];
        return;
      }
      this.categorySelectionItems = result.data.categories;
    }, // async loadCategoriesList() {
```

and in the browser I see : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hf7u.jpg

Why so and how it can be fixed ?

package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.11.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.25",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.3.1",
        "pusher-js": "^7.0.3",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.5",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
        "@johmun/vue-tags-input": "^2.1.0",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
        "ckeditor4-vue": "^1.3.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
        "secure-ls": "^1.2.6",
        "simplebar": "^5.3.0",
        "v-toaster": "^1.0.3",
        "vee-validate": "^3.4.8",
        "vue-beautiful-chat": "^2.5.0",
        "vue-facebook-login-component": "^3.0.0",
        "vue-fragment": "1.5.2",
        "vue-froala-wysiwyg": "^3.2.6-1",
        "vue-google-login": "^2.0.5",
        "vue-js-modal": "^2.0.0-rc.6",
        "vue-loading-overlay": "^3.4.2",
        "vue-plyr": "^7.0.0",
        "vue-router": "^3.4.9",
        "vue-select": "^3.12.2",
        "vue-upload-component": "^2.8.22",
        "vue-upload-multiple-image": "^1.1.6",
        "vuejs-paginate": "^2.1.0",
        "vuescroll": "^4.17.3",
        "vuex": "^3.6.2",
        "vuex-persistedstate": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "browser": {
        "crypto": false,
        "stream": false
    }
}
```

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**

I removed bootstrap-vue from the project,
and made separate page with select inputs.
It contains :

```
<template>
  <div>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div>{{ categorySelectionItems }}</div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label>Select category</label>

                      <div class="select-container">
                        <v-select
                          v-model="selection_category_id"
                          code="code"
                          label="label"
                          :options="categorySelectionItems"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Select option"
                        ></v-select>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <div>{{ platforms }}</div>
                    <label>Platform</label>
                    <div class="select-container">
                      <div class="select-container">
                        <v-select
                          v-model="selection_platform_id"
                          label="label"
                          code="code"
                          :options="platforms"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Select option"
                        ></v-select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

     </div>
</template>

<script>

import Vue from 'vue'
import vSelect from 'vue-select'

Vue.component('v-select', vSelect)
import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';

export default {
  name: "ProjectAdd",
  components: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      categorySelectionItems: [],
      selection_category_id: null,

      platforms: [{label: 'Canada', code: 'ca'}],
      selection_platform_id: null,

    };
  },
  created() {
    document.title = this.$route.meta.title;
  },

  mounted() {
    this.loadCategoriesList();

  }, // mounted() {

  methods: {

    async loadCategoriesList() {
      console.log(' loadCategoriesList:')
      const result = await this.callApi(
        'post',
        window.api_path + 'getCategoriesList',
        {mode: 'selection'}
      );
      if (result.status != 200) {
        this.$toaster.error(result.data.message);
        this.categories = [];
        return;
      }
      console.log('result.data::')
      console.log(result.data)

      this.categorySelectionItems = result.data.categories;
      console.log('this.categorySelectionItems::')
      console.log(typeof this.categorySelectionItems)
      console.log(this.categorySelectionItems)
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.categorySelectionItems)))
      console.log('======================')
      for (var i= 0; i< this.categorySelectionItems.length; i++) {
        console.log('this.categorySelectionItems[i]::')
        console.log(this.categorySelectionItems[i])
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.categorySelectionItems[i])))
        console.log(typeof this.categorySelectionItems[i])
        console.log('--')

      }
    }, // async loadCategoriesList() {


  },
  computed: {
  }
};
</script>
```

Looking at browsers console at returned data (I make output of array and any row) Observer class wrapper confuse me a lot,
but I am not sure what is the reason.

On server I return array in laravel 8 control :

```
    public function getCategoriesList(Request $request)
    {
        $mode     = $request->mode;
        $categories   = Category
            ::orderBy('title', 'asc')
            ->get()
            ->map(function ($category) use($mode) {
                return $mode == 'selection' ? [ 'code' => $category->id, 'label' => $category->title ] : $category;
            });
//            ->toArray(); // If to uncomment it - the same results!
        return response()->json(['categories' => $categories], HTTP_RESPONSE_OK);
    }
```

Please take a look at live page :

https://streamgeeks-rebranded-dev.cloudns.cl/test2

**MODIFIED BLOCK:**
That was a project started by other developer with bootstrap-vue/vuejs2 and jquery
and quite a lot of jquery libraries init code on frontend.
Working with pages I removed all bootstrap-vue/jquery code.
Now I have removed all jquery code excluding lines :

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
```

in file resources/js/bootstrap.js. But I need them as project is based on bootstrap.

It can not be a problem with css as I do not see all existing items.
In this case I would see them in browsers console.
Conflicts with other libraries?  I show package.json above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a css issue and removing in class .select-container property

```
overflow: hidden;
```

fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

From `console.log` it seems data are just fine. Do not get distracted by any `__ob__` stuff in the console. It is [normal Vue reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked)

When I inspect your example site, all seems fine - Vue Dev tools shows `:options` are bound just fine.

My theory is this is not problem of data or `v-select` (mis)configuration (there is one error but not significant - `v-select` has no `code` prop)  but rather problem with conflicting CSS (maybe because of JQuery but it is hard to say for sure)

See example below ....works just fine

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      categorySelectionItems: [{
        "code": 1,
        "label": "Broadcast"
      }, {
        "code": 2,
        "label": "Classroom"
      }, {
        "code": 3,
        "label": "Collaboration"
      }, {
        "code": 5,
        "label": "Entertainment"
      }, {
        "code": 4,
        "label": "Esports"
      }, {
        "code": 6,
        "label": "Experimental"
      }, {
        "code": 7,
        "label": "Marketing"
      }, {
        "code": 8,
        "label": "Music"
      }, {
        "code": 12,
        "label": "Other"
      }, {
        "code": 9,
        "label": "Radio"
      }, {
        "code": 10,
        "label": "Venue"
      }, {
        "code": 11,
        "label": "Worship"
      }],
      selection_category_id: null,

      platforms: [{
        label: 'Canada',
        code: 'ca'
      }],
      selection_platform_id: null,

    };
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.js"></script>

<!-- use the latest vue-select release -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest/dist/vue-select.css">

<div id="app">
  <div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Select category</label>

        <div class="select-container">
          <v-select v-model="selection_category_id" label="label" :options="categorySelectionItems" class="form-control" placeholder="Select option"></v-select>
        </div>
        <pre>selection_category_id: {{ selection_category_id }}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label>Platform</label>
      <div class="select-container">
        <div class="select-container">
          <v-select v-model="selection_platform_id" label="label" :options="platforms" class="form-control" placeholder="Select option"></v-select>
        </div>
        <pre>selection_platform_id: {{ selection_platform_id }}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED BLOCK